# Why does the set of positive definite matrices define a half-space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

A half-space is a set of the form $\{x \mid a^Tx \leq b\}$. Also it is stated that the set $$\{X \in S^n \mid z^T X z \geq 0 \}$$ where $S^n$ denote the set of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices, is a half space$^1$,

1. Can we expand it algebraically to prove it?
2. Is is possible to make a graphical intuitive example, e.g in matlab, as the one that can easily be made for $\{x \mid a^Tx \leq b\}$?

Thanks!!

---

<sup>$^{1}$*Convex Optimization* by Boyd & Vandenberghe, pp.36</sup>

Comment: The given set is defined in terms of a single vector $z\in\mathbb R^n$; it's not quantified over all $z\in\mathbb R^n$, so it's not describing the set of all positive-(semi)definite matrices. Thus the title is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$z^\top X z = (z \otimes z)^\top vec(X)$.

Now, $(z \otimes z)$ is a vector.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more? A book reference is great!:)

Comment: Well, $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). If you set $a=(z \otimes z)$, and $x=vec(X)$, then $\{X\in S^n|z^\top X z\geq 0\}$ becomes $\{x|a^\top x\geq 0\}$ and you have the definition of your half space. So, since for all PSD matrix $X$ and any vector $v$, $v^\top X v\geq 0$, all PSD matrices define a half space.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am wondering if there is an analytic proof about the equation in your answer. Can you give a book reference(e.g linear algebra book) to work on it? That would be very helpful. Thanks!!!

Comment: [Here](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~jdaunize/docs/Kronecker.pdf) is a short paper with the proof you're looking for.

Comment: I just made the prof of the theorem : $vec(ABC)=(C^T \otimes A)vec(B)$ for A and B vectors and indeed your equation is true:) Thanks for the help.

Comment: After a second thought I am wondering if we are in the scope of the prof? We where interested to prove that the sets $\{X \in S^n | z^TXz\geq 0\}$  are half spaces. However, we have proven the constrain ($z^TXz \geq 0$). Are we consistent with out goal? Thanks again:)

Comment: Again, you say a half-space is of the form $\{x|a^\top x\leq b\}$. We've shown that $z^\top X z\geq 0$ can be written in this form.

Comment: @davcha are you sure about this explanation? Consider a vector space equipped with a inner product $<.,.>$. Let $a$ be a vector in that space and $b$ be a real number. Then $\{x|<a,x> \leq b\}$ denotes a half-space in that vector space. Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^N$, the set of $N$ dimensional vectors. Then the dot-product of two vectors is a well defined innerproduct which is typically denoted as $<a,x>=a^Tx$. Consider the space of all symmetric matrices $S^n$ which is a vector space...continued

Comment: ..continued..A well used innerproduct is the trace which is defined as $<A,X>=trace(A*X)=vec(A)^Tvec(X)$. Here, it is the case that $b=0$ and $A=-zz^T$. Note that $z^TXz=trace(-A*X)$ where $A$ is as defined earlier. I think, though your answer is correct, more explanation should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Correction of the answer above, it is not (), it is infinite intersection of infinite half-spaces in n D symmetric matrix dimension. If x is vector the it belongs to Rn not Sn

Comment: A matrix is an element of the vector space of all matrices, which technically makes it a vector too, it just doesn't look like the vectors it acts on (except in the $1\times1$ case). This is a question, not an answer to this question, so I expect will be flagged for deletion.